# HTML5 website compatibility in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, html5shiv

I was going through a simple HTML5/CSS3 tutorial to build a basic website.I closely followed the tutorial to make myself understand the newly added tags use and developed what was taught online step-by-step.

However, the demo of the site I was creating worked fine on Internet-Explorer8 but when I completed my own development, though it worked fine in Chrome and Firefox but it didn't pick any design when I tried run it on Internet-Explorer8.

This however I understand is due to old versions of IE's not supporting newly added elements of HTML5 thus added a script **HTML5shiv.js**.

This should work fine however IE8 kept popping up the dialog box displaying that : **It blocked some Active Content due to security reasons and if required, you can allow them to dosplay.** This was never the case with the demo version of the website that I was making.

However, when I allowed the ActiveX controls in the IE8, everything worked fine.

The issue with me now is that if any of my website's user has disabled ActiveX-Controls in IE6,7 or 8, then my website would loose it''s designed structure. How can I get through it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are loading html5shiv.js from a separate domain, if so try downloading it and hosting it with the rest of your website. This should solve your problem.

If you're developing your website locally (i.e. directly opened from a file on your computer), that can also cause this problem.

Update to users comment:

Hosting it should solve it. Instead of buying hosting though you could simply host on your localhost, to do that look into using something such as [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/), or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/) for Mac.

Alternatively, you can add `<!-- saved from url=(0017)http://localhost/ -->` to the top of your document which should disable the security policy. You can read more about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes Ryan, I downloaded the **html5shiv.js** and added it to my files and referred to my page from there, not from any domain. Now, I assume as you said, the problem would be related to the loading of my website locally that might be causing the problem. So, if I host my application, is that going to solve the problem for me?

Comment: Hey thanks Ryan, I'll work on it and let you know if that worked.